# How do I keep Empathy from telling the other person when I am typing?

Tags: 10.10, empathy

Sometimes I start typing a message to someone then stop, rethink it and change it or not send it at all. I don't want them to see "User is typing" messages. I see no option to disable this in Empathy.

Comment: In Pidgin, the option is under Tools -> Preferences -> Conversations -> "Notify buddies that you are typing to them"

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this.

Comment: Empathy settings are now in dconf, so I've installed dconf-tools and then launched dconf-editor. No trace of such an option. Ironic that some times ago people [complained](http://ubuntu-virginia.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7965742&postcount=4) lack of this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to achieve this. Empathy itself does not really have any privacy preferences that I've seen.

Comment: I suppose this is part of their keep it simple model. Maybe you can submit a feature request to them. I wonder if it even shows the other participant that you are typing.

Comment: It definitely shows the other person that you are typing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a patch to disable sending typing notifications for Empathy 2.34.0. For now, use the first attachment.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668985

Patching 3.2.x.x is almost identical, but there are a few hunks of the patch that won't apply smoothly and need to be done by hand.